# WAR file deployment in JBoss Fuse

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fuseesb, apache-servicemix

This is regarding the WAR file deployment in JBoss Fuse ESB. 
I have a project which produces a WAR file (which contains a web application consists of some JSPs, HTMLs, and a web.inf file) together with some other bundles. 

Once I deployed them in to the FUSE, those are working properly and the WAR file is converted in to a respective bundle as well.

I can see all the bundles correctly by using a ‘list’ command in the karaf shell.

The problem I am having is I want to know the location of extracted (exploded) WAR files. 

Typically when we deploy a WAR file into a web container such as tomcat, it will extract the WAR file. 

Is it same for the JBossFuse ? or it is not extracting the WAR bundles at all ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Because I need to change some image files without deploying the war file again.

Comment: It's surely safer to just redeploy the WAR...

Answer (score 3):

In Apache Karaf WAB files are never extracted, but you can deploy an exploded WAB/WAR in the deploy folder. Just make sure the folder has the name of the war and an extension like:

```
/my-super.war/
             /index.html
             /WEB-INF/
             /WEB-INF/web.xml
```